# Jodatime: The import org.joda.time.Weeks can not be resolved

Tags: eclipse, import, jodatime, java

**Problem:-**
I want to use the class `org.joda.time.Weeks` and use it in my code. But I get this error at the import statement `import org.joda.time.Weeks;`  and an error (obviously) where I am trying to use it.

**What I have tried:** 
I downloaded the library from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/joda-time/), and included both the `.jar` files named `joda-0.9` and `joda-time-0.9` in my project's build path.

I am using Eclipse. Both the jars are *at the top and selected*, in the `order and export` section in the `Java Build Path` configuration.

But I am still getting this error.

I tried to use import `org.joda.time.*`; but no luck! I am still getting an error when I try to use the `Weeks` class.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why did you download the *oldest* available Joda Time library? In fact, this library (version 0.9) does not contain `org.joda.time.Weeks`.

I do not know, when this class was introduced, but the latest version - 2.3 - does include it. Download that.

Answer (score 1):

The class `Weeks` was introduced in version 1.4 - see the [javdoc for the class](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Weeks.html). Since 0.9 is still an alpha-version you should really use a more modern version - for example [the latest version 2.3](http://sourceforge.net/projects/joda-time/files/joda-time/).